# Calculating slope length using LS-tool

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, slope, length, erosion

Does anyone know how to get LS-tool mentioned in Zhang et al 2013.
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/256938578_Extension_of_a_GIS_procedure_for_calculating_the_RUSLE_equation_LS_factor

I tried using the Raster calculator in ArcMap 10.3.1 using the following formula by Bizuwerk et al., (2008).

LS = X/22.1m (0.065+0.045S+0.0065S^2
but I got only 0 value.

I found about LS tool after I researched on other ways to calculate slope length but can't find any place to access LS tool.

Can you help me find a way to either access LS tool or any other efficient and precise way to calculate slope length?

Answer (score 1):

In the paper mentioned in your question, the authors suggest the use the unit contributing area for the slope length. This unit contributing area can be obtained in ArcGIS using "flow accumulation" tool in Spatial analyst toolbox. Flow accumulation, by default, gives you a value in pixels, so you need to multiply by the pixel size before you divide by 22.13 (coefficient of the RUSLE equation). The best method would consist in creating a weighting raster with the **m** value and use it when you compute the accumulation.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you could try saga-gis software for creating LS. I remember that there was a module called LS Factor to create that.
Here is documentation for that module:
http://www.saga-gis.org/saga_module_doc/2.1.3/ta_hydrology_22.html